# Does Apache Ignite isolate query results in ATOMIC mode?

Tags: ignite

My app consumes 1mil records from an ATOMIC cache with a lazy SqlFieldsQuery deployed over several data nodes with one reductor node.

While the results are paged onto the reductor, a parallel client deletes keys in scope of the query.
These keys are eventually returned in a subsequent page.

Could someone confirm if query results are isolated from the main data set, then?
I did not find any mentions of that in Ignite docs.

I removed keys from an Ignite cache that were in scope of a parallel SqlFieldsQuery.
I expected the keys to not be returned from the query, but they did.

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone confirm if query results are isolated from the main data set, then? I did not find any mentions of that in Ignite docs.

Transactional SQL is supported only for caches with `TRANSACTIONAL_SNAPSHOT` [atomicity mode](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/configuring-caches/atomicity-modes). This mode enables [MVCC](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/transactions/mvcc), but MVCC is deprecated since 2.12 and will be removed in future releases.

If you are looking for ACID guarantees you should use key-value transactions as described [here](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/key-value-api/transactions).

Comment: shall i expect isolated query results in ATOMIC mode once data nodes finish fetching?